# Query returning 0 rows with sqldf package

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I am trying to retrieve some rows from my data frame using `sqldf` package but the query is returning 0 rows despite the data being there.

```
str(DATA)
'data.frame':   51500 obs. of  5 variables:
$ MaxBullProb   : Factor w/ 100 levels "CX000096 w02c05s02@CL.CC_10",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ systemid      : int  49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 ...
$ periodicityid : int  37 48 58 43 52 45 4 56 80 40 ...
$ rptday        : Date, format: "2014-11-03" "2014-11-03" "2014-11-03" "2014-11-03" ...
$ dailynetprofit: int  -620 -2000 -470 -2250 -1830 -1590 750 685 -315 -555 ...
```

The query I am running is:

```
QUERY<-"SELECT rptday,dailynetprofit from DATA WHERE rptday > '2014-11-03'"
QUERY_RES<-sqldf(QUERY)

QUERY_RES
[1] rptday         dailynetprofit
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I am not sure why the query is not working.

Comment: after doing dput(DATA), i saw that my dates are coming as 16084, etc instead of '2014-11-03'. So i replaced '2014-11-03' with 16084 and the query worked.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241030/r-date-function-in-sqldf-giving-unusual-answer-wrong-date-format/39241668

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Date"` class columns are transferred to SQLite as the number of days since the Epoch so try this.  See `?fn` .

```
library(sqldf)

compareDate <- as.Date("2014-11-03")
QUERY <- "SELECT rptday, dailynetprofit from DATA WHERE rptday > $compareDate"
fn$sqldf(QUERY)
```

which, for the one row test input in the Note below, gives:

```
      rptday dailynetprofit
1 2014-11-04           -620
```

**Note:** Test input in reproducible form is (next time please provide it like 
this):

```
DATA <- data.frame(MaxBullProb = "CX000096 w02c05s02@CL.CC_10",
                   systemid = 49,
                   periodicityid = 37,
                   rptday = as.Date("2014-11-04"),
                   dailynetprofit = -620)
```