# How to subtract a number from date

Tags: r, sqldf

How can we subtract a number from a date inside `sqldf` ?
Example:

```
sqldf("select ex_date from table where ex_date<=exdate-7")
```

I am not getting any result if I run this type of query.

Comment: Likely useful: [R: Date function in sqldf giving unusual answer (wrong date format?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39241350/496803)

Comment: Not really clear to me what you are trying to do. There can't be a result, as you are looking for a date that is smaller than itself - 7 (?). Maybe `select ex_date-7 as my_ex_date..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sqldf("select date(ex_date, '-7 day') from table")`

I'm guessing it would work, did not try it personally though.