# sqldf in R returns NA for all rows in SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, sqldf

I have a dataframe in R called "`data`". The `EventDate` column is a `date format` and the rest are double or character fields.

I'm trying to pull most of the columns from "`data`", but `aggregate` the `EventDate` values into year-month designations instead of the current year-month-day designations (so I want to end up with 01-2018, 02-2018, 03-2018, etc as the row values).

I was having a lot of trouble doing this in base R or finding any packages to do it easily. I have a lot more experience in SQL than R so I opted to use the sqldf package.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
newdata <- sqldf("SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, Staff, Type, POC, TOC1, TOC2, TOC3, CASE
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-01-01' AND EventDate < '2018-02-01' THEN 'Jan 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-02-01' AND EventDate < '2018-03-01' THEN 'Feb 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-03-01' AND EventDate < '2018-04-01' THEN 'Mar 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-04-01' AND EventDate < '2018-05-01' THEN 'Apr 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-05-01' AND EventDate < '2018-06-01' THEN 'May 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-06-01' AND EventDate < '2018-07-01' THEN 'Jun 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-07-01' AND EventDate < '2018-08-01' THEN 'Jul 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-08-01' AND EventDate < '2018-09-01' THEN 'Aug 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-09-01' AND EventDate < '2018-10-01' THEN 'Sep 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-10-01' AND EventDate < '2018-11-01' THEN 'Oct 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-11-01' AND EventDate < '2018-12-01' THEN 'Nov 2018'
  WHEN EventDate >= '2018-12-01' AND EventDate < '2019-01-01' THEN 'Dec 2018'
  END AS EventMonth
  FROM data
  ORDER BY EventMonth, Staff, ID1")
```

The code executes without any issues and produces mostly correct results, only that it returns `NA` for all rows in the `EventMonth` column of "`newdata`" instead of `"Jan 2018", "Feb 2018"`, etc.

It might be a formatting problem with the `EventDate` column in "`data`", but `data$EventDate` is listed as a date type in RStudio and it's in the `yyyy-mm-dd format`.

I also tried running the following (which doesn't error out or produce any warnings) before running the previous code as a sanity check, but it still gave me a column full of NAs for EventMonth:

```
data$EventDate <- as.Date(data$EventDate)
```

The SQL produces the expected result when I run it in SQL Server (there are no NAs in the EventMonth column), but I unfortunately won't always have access to SQL Server going forward, which is why I'm bothering with R at all.

I need a way to do this without an actual SQL database engine in order to perform similar aggregations in the future. I recently installed `R`, `RStudio`, and the `sqldf` package within the last month so I shouldn't be using anything that's horribly outdated.

Is there a way to get my desired result using **sqldf, base R, or some other R package**?

Comment: If you have a date, you can just `format` it using the needed components - `format(data$EventDate, "%m-%Y")`

Comment: There are some complications with using date objects in sqldf with a sqlite backend. You need to compare text-to-text to get the logic you're going for working - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241030/r-date-function-in-sqldf-giving-unusual-answer-wrong-date-format/39241668#39241668 and https://ladvien.com/sqldf-dates/

Comment: When asking questions on SO please show some input in reproducible form.  In this case by showing the output of `dput(head(data))` in the question.

Comment: If your input  column `EventDate` is of `Date` class then if you use the h2 backend of sqldf by issuing `library(RH2)` first then you can work with dates in the usual way in SQL.

Comment: Thank you! Using format() instead of sqldf() the way @thelatemail pointed out seems to work perfectly. I also appreciate the background on using date objects with sqldf.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the tip for posting on SO. I didn't include any of the data I'm working with to protect confidentiality, but I'll be sure to make up some dummy data next time if needed. Also, I'm still getting a column full of NAs when I try running my query with sqldf after loading the RH2 library (i.e. executing library(RH2) after installing the package). Not sure if there is something else I need to do first?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible for you to use SQLquery instead of sqldf. If yes, your query might work in this way.

I have a table like this in SQL server.

[image]

You can make a connection to your SQL server using R.

```
 library(odbc)
 library(RODBC)
 library(sqldf)

 conn <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server= 
 YOURserver;database=Yourdatabase;trusted_connection=true')

  Datanew <- sqlQuery(conn,"SELECT ID,Dates,Amount  ,
  case when Dates >= '2018-01-01' and Dates < '2018-02-01' then 'Jan 2018'
                when Dates >= '2018-02-01' and Dates < '2018-03-01' then 'Feb 2018' 
                when Dates >= '2018-03-01' and Dates < '2018-04-01' then 'Mar 2018' 
  end as Months, 
                 format(dates,'MMM yyyy') NewapproachDates
                FROM dbo.practicR;"); 

View(Datanew)
```

You case statement to convert dates to Month and year is correct but this format function will be lot easier as you don't have to give date range every time like you are doing in case statement. There are two columns for dates (one is the way you have provided and another is new way)

Output is this:

[image]