# Can u help me translate this core from SQL to R

Tags: sql, r

```sql
SELECT  titlu
FROM carti i INNER JOIN 
     carti_autori d 
     ON i.isbn=d.isbn INNER JOIN 
     autori u 
     ON d.cod_autor=u.cod_autor
WHERE nume_autor = 'Dumitriu Florin'  

INTERSECT

SELECT titlu
FROM carti i INNER JOIN 
     carti_autori d 
     ON i.isbn=d.isbn INNER JOIN 
     autori u 
     ON d.cod_autor=u.cod_autor
WHERE nume_autor='Georgescu Mircea'

except

SELECT titlu
FROM carti i INNER JOIN 
     carti_autori d 
     ON i.isbn=d.isbn INNER JOIN 
     autori u 
     ON d.cod_autor=u.cod_autor
WHERE nume_autor != 'Georgescu Mircea' and 
      nume_autor != 'Dumitriu Florin'
```

Comment: Which table is ```nume_autor``` from?

Comment: You don't need to translate .. you can make use of SQLdf package and use the same query .. you can refer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031288/sqldf-in-r-returns-na-for-all-rows-in-sql-case-statement/54034263#54034263

Comment: nume_autor is from Autori